# WPF TreeView not sorting at top-level

Tags: wpf, treeview

I have a WPF TreeView control that I am trying to sort using a CollectionViewSource. The TreeView has a hierarchy consisting of 4 levels. Levels 2,3 and 4 all sort correctly. However, the top level does not. The TreeView is populated by objects of type IOrderItem at all four levels. The only difference between the top level and levels 2,3 and 4 is that the top level can contain a mixture of different types of object that derive from IOrderItem, whereas levels 2, 3 and 4 will only contain one of the types. I suspect that the top level will not sort due to the polymorphic nature of the objects within it. Has anyone come across this issue? There are similar posts but they all seem to refer to the items in the top level being sorted but those in lower levels not. This is the opposite to the problem I am experiencing.
Any help greatly appreciated.
Roger.

Comment: Can't you just use linq to sort the underlying collection?

Comment: Thanks Andy. That's works a treat. It does beg the question why anyone would use a CollectionViewSource in the first place.